# wget do not download subirectories only all files in specified directory

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I can't find a way to only download all files in a specific directory without going into sub directories. If I don't use `-r` I only download the `index.html`

```
wget -np -nH --cut-dirs 4 -l2 http://hydrology.princeton.edu/data/pgf/1.0deg/3hourly/
```

If I add `-r` goes into subdirectories. Is there a way to avoid the `--exclude` flag and get all files in the 3hourly directory?

Comment: Tried this: wget -r -l1

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have already the no parent flag 'np' but the problem is not the parent but the subdirectories that I don't want.

Comment: @gonephishing that works but it needs to be combined with -nd, not sure why